# Nicematrix and aligned math

Tags: align, matrices, split, nicematrix

The following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{split}
            \alpha^{d+i}_i
            &=\begin{pmatrix}
                \alpha^{d+i}_{i-1} & (-1)^i \phi^{d+1}_{i-2} \\
                0 & f^{d+1}_{i-2}
            \end{pmatrix}\\
            &=
            \begin{pNiceMatrix}
                \partial_{d+i} & \phi^{d+i-1}_0 & -\phi^{d+i-2}_1 & \Block{2-1}{\phi^{d+i-3}_2} & \Block[name=a]{3-1}{-\phi^{d+i-4}_4} &        & \Block[name=b]{5-1}{\pm \phi^{d+1}_{i-2}} \\
                {}             & 0              & f^{d+i-2}_1     &                             &                                      &        &  \\
                {}             &                & 0               & f^{d+i-3}_2                 &                                      &        &  \\
                {}             &                &                 & 0                           & f^{d+i-4}_3                          &        &                                           \\
                {}             &                &                 &                             & \Ddots                               & \Ddots &                                           \\
                {}             &                &                 &                             &                                      &        & f^{d+1}_{i-2}                             \\
                {}             &                &                 &                             &                                      &        & 0 \\
                \CodeAfter
                \line{a}{b}
            \end{pNiceMatrix}.
        \end{split}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

produces the following warnings:

> Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. D
> id you specify a point identical to the center of node `nm-1-a''? on input lin e 23. Package pgf Warning: Returning node center instead of a point on node border. D id you specify a point identical to the center of node` nm-1-b''? on input lin
> e 23.

If the `split`-environment (and the alignment points and newlines) are removed, the warning disappears. Same is true for `align*`.

What's happening? How to remove the warning?

Comment: (I'm the author of `nicematrix`). I will post on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` which will solve that problem.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thank you! Is there anything I can do in the meantime? If not, I guess there is no big problem, because the output looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.19a of 2023-05-25), you won't have any message in the second compilation (you may have one in the first compilation but, anyway, your example requires two compilations).